# How to save data changed in datagridview to a database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I have a simple form with `DataGridView` thas uses `DataSet`'s `DataTable`s as a data source. I need to save data added, changed or deleted in the `DataGridView` to the database. However, there is a catch. I don't have all the database information hardcoded. Instead, user inputs it at the runtime. I was trying to use `SqlCommandBuilder`, but it looks like the database has to have an unique identifier in order for it to work. Is there any other way around? Or do i have to limit the user to use only databases with unique identifiers? And even then, do i have to write custom commands for insert/delete/update? Or standart methods will work?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! - _..it looks like the database has to have an unique identifier in order for it to work._ Of course. A DBMS will __always__ call for a unique identifier. How else could it work? How else could it __identify__ the rows??? A Table without is terribly bad design.

Comment: @TaW edited the title, thanks

Comment: Another rule a DBMS should follow is it must supply tables ('systables') with complete system information.  You will be able to query them an find out anything you need from types to keys, fks, views etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure where you are going with your application so I may be a little of base with some details below, but feel free to leave some comments and I'll try to restructure the answer if I'm off base.

First, if you are building an application of any size, consider using [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than winforms.  It provides significantly more power and flexibility and is recommended over winforms.  If you do use WPF, then you should take a look at the [MVVM pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) to track your data.

As far as the user choosing a database at runtime.  Do you have a finite set of Databases that can be connected to?  If so you can set the connection details behind the scenes and let the user select from a dropdown which connection they want to use.

For reading/writing to a database I would recommend using the [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx).